# Phpseclib on error execute different command

Tags: php, linux, ssh, phpseclib

I am using Phpseclib 1.0 to execute multiple commands on remote server . I know how configure it to exit on error but is there any way to setup that if there is error it will stop and execute different commands ? For example I have 8 commands to execute when it all works it's don't show any output so it's all good . if for example after 4th command it gets error I need that it stop to execute the rest commands and execute command to delete what it did as well another command to run another script to notify admins about accident. The current code I using is

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('host');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo '<pre>' .   $ssh->exec('create vlan “TEST”') . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' .   $ssh->exec('configure vlan TEST tag 666') . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' .   $ssh->exec('configure vlan TEST add ports 8 untagged') . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' .   $ssh->exec('create l2vpn vpws TEST fec-id-type pseudo-wire 666') . '</pre>';

// Execute on error
echo '<pre>' .   $ssh->exec('delete l2vpn vpws “TEST”') . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' .   $ssh->exec('delete vlan “TEST”') . '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Please add some code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You have very strange quotation marks `“...”`, not sure if they actually even work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could check stderr by doing `$ssh->getStdError()` and seeing if it's empty. There's also `$ssh->getExitStatus()`.

Comment: This I read on phpseclib website but I'm not sure how to make when one of commands return error instead of continue executing commands it will execute different commands . I know I can use `set -e` but if error it will stop the whole thing.

Comment: @George - what about something like this?: https://pastebin.com/BBj2gUAX

Comment: I already using different solution , want to check yours but it was giving error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in testnew.php on line 16`

Comment: @George - `if (strlen($ssh->getStdError()) {` should have an extra closing. paranthesis. That said... if I might ask, how long have you been programming / doing PHP? Knowing that will give me a better idea of whether or not I can just point you in the right direction or if I need to full on just write out syntax free code for you. Pointing you in the right direction is certainly less effort for me but if that's also less useful for you it'd be good to know that.